# How Large is the Wurm Client?

Tags: wurm-online

The game client download from the Wurm Online site appears to be a downloader.  Unfortunately, there's no way to tell the filesize of the actual game client.

Does anyone know roughly how big it is?

Comment: The size of the client will change every time the game is updated or patched, and as such I'm voting to close this as "Too Localized".

Comment: On a scale from one to large, this could probably be answerable... but I see your point.  However, I'm going to let the community decide before I delete it myself.

Comment: It's 8 MBs. See this thread: http://wurmonline.com/forum/index.php?topic=14763.0

Comment: @Bora: Well, it was 8 MB about 3 years ago anyway.

Comment: @GnomeSlice It exists once more.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer can change as time goes on.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ the same could be said about most questions on Arqade.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ The fact that an answer can change due to an update to the game is not a reason to pre-emptivey close a question, as we'd be closing all [tag:minecraft], [tag:world-of-warcraft] and who knows how many other questions as soon as they are asked.

Answer (score 2):

The Wurm client itself is about 8 MB, but it will download a graphics (521 MB) and a sound pack (106 MB), which adds up to a **total of 635 MB**. The actual number will vary over time as client, sound and graphics are updated regularly.

The updater is smart enough to only download the new/changed parts and not re-download the entire packs when they are updated.

Answer (score 0):

Initial download is tiny, however it then downloads sound and texture packs that total about 1 gig.